# Theme.NoDisplay creates strage delay

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a strange error when using the `Theme.NoDisplay` theme: It makes it extremely slow to show another activity!

I open an invisible activity from a notification, which in turn opens a new activity depending on the intent action.

If I use any other theme, like `Theme.AppCompat`, then it takes a around 300ms to open the input dialog. With the `Theme.NoDisplay` theme, it takes about 5 seconds!

If I use logcat, then I can see that `onCreate`, `onResume`, etc. in the `InputActivity` is called some milliseconds after the invisible activity is created, but until it actually is visible, it takes several seconds. I don't understand how that theme can create that effect or how to solve it (without using a service).

The invisible activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".InvisibleActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
```

The activity to open:

```
<activity
    android:name=".InputActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:label="@string/lblAddTime"
    android:theme="@style/theme.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

The intent from the notification:

```
Intent stopIntent = new Intent(context, InvisibleActivity.class);
stopIntent.setAction(InvisibleActivity.STOP_TIMER);
stopIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pStopIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, stopIntent, 0);
```

And in `onCreate` in `InvisibleActivity`, this is called:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InputActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: "What I do is to open an invisible activity from a notification, which in turn opens a new activity depending on the intent action" -- if it only depends upon the `Intent` action, why not configure the right activity in the `Notification` in the first place? What are you gaining by using the `Theme.NoDisplay` activity here? Also, are you `finish()`-ing the `Theme.NoDisplay` activity after starting the real activity?

Comment: The problem might be that I delay the finish call, even if I do call it. Does it have to be done before onResume?

Comment: "Does it have to be done before onResume?" -- not necessarily; I'm just trying to guess what your problem might be. "even if I do call it" -- I suspect that the task stack will continue to have an "invisible activity" in it if you don't `finish()` it, and that could lead to navigation issues for the user.

Comment: I delay the finish call by three seconds. If I call it directly at the end of onCreate, then the InputActivity is displayed immediately. Don't really understand how that matters for the second dialog to be displayed. Visible activities doesn't have that problem when starting another activity.

Comment: "Don't really understand how that matters for the second dialog to be displayed" -- neither do I, but that would appear to be your solution.

Comment: I delay it by this code at the end of onCreate:  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    InvisibleActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }, 3000);

Answer (score 2):

If there is someone looking for what to use instead of

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

use

```
android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display4"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old, but if any one wonders, [this link](https://plus.google.com/+DianneHackborn/posts/LjnRzJKWPGW) talks about why this happens:

> PSA: The new requirement to immediately finish an activity if using
>   Theme.NoDisplay is not a regression, this has always been a
>   requirement of it (see
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoDisplay
>   for example).
>
> The reason the platform in M is now crashing the app if it doesn't use
>   this is because not using it would previously break in very subtle and
>   mysterious ways.  For example, you would sometimes end up with your
>   app ANRing for no reason.